# OrientDB Java API

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm trying to work with OrientDB using Java API. My aim is to add some vertices to fresh created database.

First of all I created connection to database

graph = new OrientGraphFactory("PLOCAL:localhost/affiliates", "admin", "admin").getNoTx();

Next through some iteration I created some amount of vertices

```
private Vertex createVertex(Company company) {
    Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex(company);
    //vertex.setProperty("id", company.getId());
    if (company.getName() != null) {
        vertex.setProperty("name", company.getName());
    }
    if (company.getInn() != null) {
        vertex.setProperty("inn", company.getInn());
    }
    if (company.getOgrn() != null) {
        vertex.setProperty("ogrn", company.getOgrn());
    }
    return  vertex;
}
```

After that (in that session) I've calculated created vertices like this:

```
    Integer vertexCount = 0;
    Iterable vertices = graph.getVertices();
    while (vertices.iterator().hasNext()) {
        Vertex vertex = (Vertex) vertices.iterator().next();
        vertexCount++;
    }
    log.info("vertexCount = " + vertexCount);
```

And found the same amount of vertices as I expected (100 vertices).

After that I'm trying to see those vertices in OrientDB console and see nothing

```
orientdb {db=affiliates}> classes


CLASSES
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-----+
|#   |NAME       |SUPER-CLASSES|CLUSTERS    |COUNT|
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-----+
|0   |_studio    |             |_studio(12) |    1|
|1   |E          |             |e(10)       |    0|
|2   |OFunction  |             |ofunction(6)|    0|
|3   |OIdentity  |             |-           |    0|
|4   |ORestricted|             |-           |    0|
|5   |ORole      |[OIdentity]  |orole(4)    |    3|
|6   |OSchedule  |             |oschedule(8)|    0|
|7   |OSequence  |             |osequence(7)|    0|
|8   |OTriggered |             |-           |    0|
|9   |OUser      |[OIdentity]  |ouser(5)    |    3|
|10  |V          |             |v(9)        |    0|
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-----+
|    |TOTAL      |             |            |    7|
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-----+
```

What I've missed?

Comment: Does the web interface show the same result?

Comment: Try a eelect from E or select from V

Comment: Did you want to use a PLOCAL or REMOTE database?

Comment: @efekctive Yeah, the same

Comment: @efekctive I've selected from E and from V. There are no records.

Comment: @cricket_007 I connected in PLOCAL mode - PLOCAL:localhost/affiliates

Comment: Let me check my code one sec

Comment: I use commit() everywhere except when I am using orient in memory. If you try to run the while loop alone do you still get the 100 vertices?

Comment: I used to use commit() too. Now, as you can see I'm using non transaction connection `graph = new OrientGraphFactory("PLOCAL:localhost/affiliates", "admin", "admin").getNoTx();` There are no vertices in base.

Comment: But if you disconnect and connect running the while loop ALONE do you still see the vertices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134017/discussion-between-alex-zhulin-and-efekctive).

Comment: I have code myself that uses `remote:localhost/database`, then the `graphFactory.getNoTx()`, and I still use `commit()`. Works fine